# Saving multiple tags with Select2 and syncing to posts

Tags: php, laravel, tags, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to select tags in my post but I would like to implement the tagging feature. I am able to save new tags but I am stuck linking the tag to the post on my pivot table.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value:  'bike'
>   for column 'tag_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `post_tag`  (`post_id`,
>   `tag_id`) values (167, bike))

```php
$post = new Post;
$post->post_category_id = $request->post_category_id;
$post->title = $request->title;
$post->body = $request->body;
$post->meta_description = $request->meta_description;
$post->slug = $request->slug;
$post->user_id = auth()->id();

$tags = $request->input('tags');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if (is_numeric($tag)) {
        $tagArr[] = $tag;
    } else {
        $newTag = Tag::create(['name' => $tag]);
        $newTag = $newTag->id;
    }
}

$post->save();
$post->featured()->sync($request->featured, false);
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was saved successfully!');

return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
```

I know I can change the `tag_id` to a string but I wondered if there was another way around it.

Comment: examining the error above, it says its expecting an integer, but you gave it a `bike` instead

Comment: and your `$tagArr` is supposed to be filled up but not used in any way

Comment: bike is the name of the tag this is where i am stuck i dont know how to save the tag id instead of the name

Comment: the clue is already on the first comment, you provided `bike` which means your html select markup in the value attribute should be tag id's in the first place, not the literal word `bike`

Comment: I must be missing somthing ghost? The name of the tag bike. This saved on to my tags table. please tell me how to take the tag id interger and save it as a value.

Comment: i can change tag_id to a sting but i dont want to do that